# Removing Selected rows in a datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c#-express-2010

I am currently using this code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
}
```

I have checkmarks down the first column, but with this code, it only get the selected. How do i get the Selected CheckBoxes *only* to delete with the row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i]
                          .Cells[yourCheckBoxColIndex].Value) == true)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i); 
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var checked = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value); // Assuming the first column contains the Checkbox
    if(checked)
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be something like this... This is an example for listview, however the concept is almost there. Loop through the item and find the checkbox id and remove those selected. Hope this helps.

```
public void btnDeleteClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Iterate through the ListViewItem
        foreach (ListViewItem row in ListView1.Items)
        {
            // Access the CheckBox
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("cbxID");
            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {
                // ListView1.DataKeys[item.DisplayIndex].Values[0].ToString()
                try
                {

                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count>0)
        {
            dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(dgv.CurrentRow.Index);
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int s = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = s - 1; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1["Stok", j].Value) < 5)
                { s = j; dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(j); break; }
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
```